# Continue sending push notification discarding failed device ones for ios

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to send push notifications to 1000s (thousands) of devices at once(in batch) for ios.
 What I need is,

if error occurs for some device tokens (let's say 100th token),
 I need to discard sending push notification to that token only and continue from next device token(101th).

In my database, there are production tokens but some are development too. I don't know which of them are production and which ones are development tokens. I am using production certificate. I think, due to some development tokens, push is not sent to all devices.

So, is there any possibility of distinguishing development or production? Or, simply discard if error occurs for one token and continue with next token. I am using PHP for service side of push notification.

Answer (score 0):

The only sure way to find the development tokens is to detect error responses of invalid device tokens returned from Apple (assuming that you send the notifications in the enhanced binary format).

Another way, if you know the full list of devices you used when testing APNS in development, is to try installing the development build on those devices and get the development tokens when registering to APNS. This is only practical if you have a small number of such devices.

Comment: How to detect errors. I mean how to exactly know which token is invalid? And, after detecting the invalid token, should I need to remove those tokens or ignore them? I cannot do your another way, because there are 1000s of users. Can you please suggest me how to handle this problem? Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: @BarcelonaTsandesh Even if there are 1000s of users, I should imagine there was a much smaller number of devices used for development. As for detecting errors, in the enhanced format you send a message with an identifier. If you get an error response, it contains a message ID, and from that ID you can find the device token of that message (if you store that data in your server). It's best to remove invalid tokens, and not to mix development tokens with production tokens in the same DB.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But can you help me detecting the invalid tokens? Any tutorials, docs or sample code??

Comment: @BarcelonaTsandesh Check [this](http://learn-php-by-example.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/working-with-apple-push-notification.html) out.